# Assign User to net use to change another users password

Tags: cmd, net-use

Is it possible to assign a user to make net use run as a certain person(admin) to change another users password? Like so?:

`"/c net user /user:domain\Administrator <admin-pwd> username password /domain"`

Maybe some how using a runas or something to tell the command to run as a certain individual?

Comment: This question is better suited to the Super User site. http://superuser.com/

Comment: ok thanks ill try it there